# urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError in python requests

Tags: python-3.x

I have trying to work on the requests module but i have been getting this error again and again. I looked at many similar posts but none of them helped me get past this error.

```
import json
import requests

    r = requests.get("http://mysafeinfo.com/api/data?list=englishmonarchs&format=json",timeout=3)
```

Below is the error:

**urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='mysafeinfo.com', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/data?list=englishmonarchs&format=json (Caused by : [Errno -2] Name or service not known)**

Answer (score -3):

You can pass `allow_redirects=False` as argument of requests.get method to solve the issue. So your code looks like follows:

```
import json
import requests

r = requests.get("http://mysafeinfo.com/api/data?list=englishmonarchs&format=json",timeout=3, allow_redirects=False)
```

[requests allow_redirects](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#redirection-and-history)

Comment: There's nothing in the question to suggest this is related to redirects.